# CSS Submenu Scrolling with Page

Tags: css, wordpress, scroll, submenu

Hi I had to create a horizontal submenu for a website using wordpress. I just have 1 more problem, when you scroll over the link when halfway down the page the submenu appears halfway down the page. I believe this to be because of:

```
position: fixed;
        top: 264px;
        left: 50%;
        width: 1000px;
        margin-left:-500px;
```

Is there a way to fix this?

The website is: http://dev.timson.me (Submenus on "Upcoming" & "Past Productions")

And the CSS is:

```
#access {
clear: both;
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0 auto 6px;
padding-top: 8px;
width: 100%;
font-family: Stag;
display:block;
text-align:center;
}

#access ul {
    font-size: 13px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 -0.8125em;
    padding-left: 0;

    display:inline-block;
}

.sub-menu {
    text-align: center;
}

#menu-default > li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.sub-menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#access a {
    color: #eee;
    display: block;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-top: -4px;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
    padding: 0 1.2125em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#access ul ul {

    display: none;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 264px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 1000px;
    z-index: 99999;
    margin-left:-500px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:10px;

    background: red;
}

#access ul ul a {

    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-bottom:10px;

}

#access ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could clean up a lot of the css ultimately repairing your issue.

```
//Remove left margin
#access div {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
}

ul, ol {
    margin: 0;
}

//Remove left margin
#access ul {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    padding-left: 0;
```

}

```
//remove position relative, it is now located in the access div container. 
#menu-default > li {
    float:left
}

#access ul ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 23px;
    width: 1000px;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

You may need to adjust the vertical padding with the sub nav. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of

```
position: fixed;
```

And that should do it.

Comment: Hmm.  Does not fix it for me (FF 10.0.2).